# Magnetic coil with AC calculation

Tags: electromagnetism

For the project of nondestructive testing of metal parts I have to calculate a coil with radius $R=0.4m$ that should produce $H=300 A/cm$ with supplied 50 Hz AC. I have to decide on number of turns and anything else that would make the coil feasible for real life application.
My thinking goes as follows:
for a solenoid $ H = {n\times I}/{\sqrt(l^2+4R^2)}=300A/cm$  we get the current $I =48000/n \space A$ where $n$ is the number of turns.
Coil impedance $X=2 \pi f \cdot L=2 \pi f \cdot  \left(\frac{\mu\mu_0n^2S}{l}\right)$ where $f=50Hz $, $L$ is inductance, $S$ is the square of the coil, $l$ is the length of the coil.
Corresponding voltage amplitude $U=IX = ...=256\cdot n \space V$.
This gives a power of $P=UI=12.3 MW$ which makes the coil completely unusable for real life purposes.

Questions:

1. is my calculation wrong?
2. what could be a trick to get a real life solution ($P \approx 300-500 kW$) for $300 A/cm$ field with $50Hz$ current? Making 10 turns and coil length of 1m gives $P=2.5 MW$ which is still unusable.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: How about adding a ferromagnetic core?